# Installing PySCIPOpt on Ubuntu 16

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, scip

I want to use SCIP on Python3 on Ubuntu. Pretty much clueless. I couldn't find a step by step guide. My attempt to install the interface "PySCIPOpt" gets me this:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
Installing collected packages: PySCIPOpt
Running setup.py install for PySCIPOpt ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tl0gl49o/PySCIPOpt/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-be931oqd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/Multidict.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/scip.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/scip.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/conshdlr.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/propagator.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/heuristic.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/expr.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/presol.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/sepa.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/branchrule.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/lp.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/pricer.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    copying src/pyscipopt/event.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyscipopt
    running build_ext
    building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/pyscipopt
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-tl0gl49o/PySCIPOpt/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/pyscipopt/scip.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/pyscipopt/scip.o
    src/pyscipopt/scip.c:548:23: fatal error: scip/scip.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tl0gl49o/PySCIPOpt/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-be931oqd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tl0gl49o/PySCIPOpt/
```

Here are the steps I went through:

1. Download
   http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipoptsuite-5.0.1.tgz
2. Extract it to
   /home/crystal/software/SCIPSuide/SCIPOptSuite-5.0.1-Linux
3. Export
   SCIPOPTDIR=/home/crystal/software/SCIPSuide/SCIPOptSuite-5.0.1-Linux
4. Download PySCIPOpt-master from git
5. `sudo python3 setup.py install` in extracted folder PySCIPOpt-master

Comment: Downloading the SCIP OPT Suite is not enough. You also have to `make` and `make install` it, see [these instructions](http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/CMAKE.php). Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to compile everything from source? Just download and run the [Debian/Ubuntu installer for the SCIP Optimization Suite](http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=SCIPOptSuite-5.0.1-Linux.deb). Then run `pip install pyscipopt`.

It's all explained [here](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.rst).

And I strongly suggest to work within a [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) for Python and not to install Python modules using `sudo`. You might also want to check out [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download) for organizing your Python environment.